# Is MikTeX 22.3 the latest version for Windows LaTeX?

Tags: miktex

Dear friends: Due to some reasons, I am trying to reinstall LaTeX in my Windows.. I got MikTeX 22.3 (64 bit). Basic install I am using. Is it the latest version? I need the full package, but I hope that basic install is enough to start my work, as I need to run LaTeX urgently for my class notes. Thanks!

Comment: Does one of the provided answers solve your problem? You did give any feedback so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go to the official website and download the latest version, see https://miktex.org/download.

Of use the **Net Installer** that let's you install the complete feature set (my recommendation).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I know the current version  number of Miktex in my computer?

Answer (score 3):

Sundar, according to what is reported on the official site, https://miktex.org/download, it seems that MikTeX 22.3 (64 bit), is the latest version, however, if you have problems with the installation and operation of MikTeX, you can try to install TexLive which you can get from ctan.org, which works very well. I hope your doubt will be clarified.